# Chartkick stuck at loading

Tags: chartkick

I'm using chartkick 2.2.5 on Rails and I can't get to show the graph on the view. I followed the installation process in the documentation and still the graphs doesn't appear to be loading.
This are the files I have:

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
 .
 .
 .
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.raty
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= yield :charts_js %>
```

initializers/chartkick.rb

```
Chartkick.options[:content_for] = :charts_js
```

At first I got a "Chartkick is not defined" exception but after I tried adding the content_for options it seems be gone.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I forgot to add chartkick script to active admin initializer, since I wanted to display it in the administrator